# Managing window size with respect to the taskbar

Tags: winapi, taskbar

How can I resize my application's window when the taskbar's size has changed?

For example, when the taskbar has been reduced in size my window should increase in size to fill up the hole that was created.  My window should never overlap the taskbar.

I was able to create the window in the correct place by calling `CreateWindowEx` with a position derived from calling `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &rectWorkArea, 0);`

Now, when I increase the taskbar's size my window's size decreases automatically
without any code. But when I "go back", my window remains in its current position.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You are seeing standard behaviour.  I wouldn't change it without a good reason.  Windows that are maximized (or in Windows 7's semi-maximized state, what do you call that?) are automatically resized to fill the screen (or the screen height) without you having to do anything.  Other windows are moved out of the way when the taskbar is expanded, but aren't resized when the taskbar is shrunk.  This is normal.

Comment: Good to know...well, I've asked since I notice some programs are doing this kind of thing...so I've felt a lack in my application.:|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not judging if it is good or wrong idea (as standard applications just don't do it), I think it can be tracked by handling `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` in any top-level window.